# Optimization Modelling: Formulating an Optimal Revenue Strategy With Multiple Constraints

Tags: probability, optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, gambling

I'm working on a project where the goal is to develop a scheme that computes the optimal solution to the following problem:

Consider a non-virtual loot box; a fix-priced bundle of distinct merchandise that differ in price, with varying probabilities for winning a specific merchandise. Determine the revenue-optimal combination of price and allocation probabilities. Incorporate a salvage mechanism by which a customer can trade in unwanted items for a partial refund.

---

I suppose we could determine the weighed averages of the outcomes:

$$E\lbrack X\rbrack=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\,p_i$$

So if there are $n-$possibilities, we multiply their likelihood of occurring by their price and sum it all up. And we want it to be so that the sum of gross profit after $n-$times is greater than the price to open it $n-$times. We could then find different probability distributions that keep this net revenue $\gt 0$, by varying one parameter and changing the other(s) to compensate. But this seems to me a rather naive, brute-force approach.

Would it be correct to frame this problem as an optimization problem?

There are some constraints that must be satisfied:

- $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$.
- Suppose we set the lower bound to $0.1$ percent. Thus, for each $p_i\geq 0.001$.
- Items within a box are categorized into multiple rarity classes (each item is assigned to a specific class),
  and are allocated probabilities based on their currency values. Items of higher value should be assigned 
  lower probabilities. Thus, $p_1\leq p_2 \leq...\leq p_n$.
- The currency value $C$ of a particular box, that is, the cost to open should be bounded; obviously we can't have boxes costing thousands of dollars to open, so we bound $C$ to a reasonable range, perhaps $\lbrack 1,50\rbrack$. As an aside, the value of a particular item $\large c_i$ within a box can be greater than $C$.
- $0 \leq c_1 \leq c_2 \leq ...\leq c_n$.

Also, consider the situation where a customer would like to take advantage of the salvage mechanic; we would need to determine the optimal fraction of $\large c_i$ to refund while still maintain positive revenue.

Lastly, if I'm not mistaken, the decision variables are $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ and $C$.

---

I've only a superficial knowledge of optimization and would appreciate any insights in to formulating my problem mathematically as an optimization problem. My end goal would be something that's implementable in a modelling language to use with an optimization solver, or implementable in a general purpose programming language.

Comment: What you are probably missing is a goal and a tradeoff. Goal is easy, you want to make more money. The tradeoff is tricky: there should be a reason why it's _not_ best for you to only put the cheapest stuff into the chest.  And the reason is that you want to maximize total income, i.e. #chests sold * money you make per chest. The problem is that #chests sold will depend on what you put into the chests and how much they cost. You have to describe this dependency or at least estimate it based on reasonable guesses...